# How to identify right partition from GParted

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

[image]I am trying to re-install GRUB to enable booting Ubuntu (as it defaults to Win 10 currently). I followed other post, and below is copy paste of the instructions for the same. Could anyone please help me identify what is the value of sdX, sdXX and sdXXX. I have copy pasted my GParted screen shot above. Many thanks.

sudo mount /dev/sdXXX /mnt

sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt/boot/efi

for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/sdX

update-grub

Note:

sdX = disk | sdXX = efi partition | sdXXX = system partition

Answer (score 0):

In general most of the guides you see write `sdX` where “sd” stands for SCSI disk. I can see in your case you have an NVMe disk, so the names as shown in Gparted would be `nvme0n1XXXX`

Your disk name is `nvme0n1` so it depends on where you want to mount the root partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p8 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**Edit:** before installing grub
use [genfstab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/genfstab.1.html) to fill the fstab file **after** mounting the partitions

```
genfstab / > /etc/fstab
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
```

**Edit:** genfstab is a script in the Arch installation package and can be installed `sudo apt-get install -y arch-install-scripts` to help with the generation of the fstab file. however you can write your own fstab as described [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-fstab-works-introduction-to-the-etc-fstab-file-on-linux)

Comment: thank you SamyAbdellatif for your help. I just ran the commands and unfortunately still unable to boot into Ubuntu. Seems I am now loosing hope of running this OS on my new PC :(. Anything more you could suggest I try doing ?

Comment: try to open your bios and check if there is option to change the UEFI boot order and make GRUB on top of Windows boot manager , .... what I got from your words that you have ubuntu and windows 10 installed side by side and the boot takes you to windows 10 not GRUB menu .. am I correct? can you edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f` ..

Comment: first try the bios settings .. in case it didn't help try to boot using live linux and install boot-repair as it says [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) ..

Comment: Hi SamyAbdellatif, thanks for your help. I have added output of cat /etc/fstab and lsblk -f as advised. I also ran boot-repair in live linux, got pop-up confirming that boot repair is successful. Still not able to see 'Grub' in boot manager and default booting into Win 10 :(

Comment: You should do this after the step where you do >sudo chroot /mnt 
The output of the fstab file you included is from the live image not the installed system

Comment: I am unable to boot into installed system. I ran live ubuntu and ran genfstab command per your update above. I got error of 'genfstab: command not found'

Comment: the genfstab is a script under the package “arch-install-scripts” , you need to install it first , you download it from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/admin/arch-install-scripts) .. and anyway you can write the fstab yourself

Comment: Thanks SamyAbdellatif, assume i can install it on live Ubuntu ? Will do it tonight.

Comment: Couldn't install the package “arch-install-scripts”  :(

Comment: Any other suggestion please ?